# How to correctly register a CMS element with the Shopware 6 Admin SDK

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

With the Shopware 6 Admin SDK it's possible to add [CMS Elements](https://shopware.github.io/admin-extension-sdk/docs/guide/api-reference/cms/registerCmsElement) to the Shopware Admin from an external app via iFrame. However, by following the [documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-cms-element-via-admin-sdk) there are some issues one might tackle along the way. If everything is done as stated in the docs following issues occur that I'd like to discuss:

- **First issue:** If the newly registered CMS element is used more than once in a shopping experience layout the same config data is shared between all elements. This is the most severe issue that I need to solve. The second issue sounds kind of the reason for it. Therefore I attached my code at the end.
- **Second issue:** Once the newly registered CMS element's config modal is opened the following error is thrown: `The dataset id "swag-dailymotion__config-element" you tried to publish is already registered.` The error is thrown in this [file](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/core/service/extension-api-data.service.ts#L72). I guess this has something to do in which I set up the element.
- **Third issue:** If e.g. some text element is exchanged with the newly registered element the following console error is thrown once the element switch button is clicked and all element previews are visible: `An error was captured in current module: TypeError: this.initElementConfig is not a function`. Since there is a `// @ts-expect-error` in the [responsible file](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-cms/elements/location-renderer/preview/index.ts#L43) I think this is not too important for the extension developer, since Shopware is already aware of it.

I have the following setup for implementing the CMS element. It differs in some way, since I am using `.vue` files instead of plain `.ts` as explained in the docs. However, except the mentioned issues, everything seems to be working fine:

This file is the entry point for the `<base-app-url>`

```js
<template>
    <view-renderer v-if="showViewRenderer"></view-renderer>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { location, cms } from '@shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk';
import viewRenderer from '@/components/cms/view-renderer.vue';
import { CONSTANTS } from '@/components/cms/index';

export default Vue.extend({
    components: {
        'view-renderer': viewRenderer
    },

    data() {
        return {
            showViewRenderer: false
        };
    },

    created(): void {
        if (location.isIframe()) {
            if (location.is(location.MAIN_HIDDEN)) {
                this.mainCommands();
            } else {
                this.showViewRenderer = true;
            }
        }
    },

    methods: {
        mainCommands(): void {
            this.registerCmsElements();
        },

        registerCmsElements(): void {
            cms.registerCmsElement({
                name: CONSTANTS.CMS_ELEMENT_NAME,
                label: this.$t('cms.dailymotion.preview.label') as string,
                defaultConfig: {
                   dailyUrl: {
                      source: 'static',
                      value: '',
                   },
                },
            });
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

@/components/cms/view-renderer.vue

```js
<template>
    <div>
        <swag-dailymotion-config v-if="location.is('swag-dailymotion-config')"></swag-dailymotion-config>
        <swag-dailymotion-element v-else-if="location.is('swag-dailymotion-element')"></swag-dailymotion-element>
        <swag-dailymotion-preview v-else-if="location.is('swag-dailymotion-preview')"></swag-dailymotion-preview>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue from 'vue';
import { location } from '@shopware-ag/admin-extension-sdk';
import swagDailymotionConfig from '@/components/cms/swag-dailymotion/swag-dailymotion-config.vue';
import swagDailymotionElement from '@/components/cms/swag-dailymotion/swag-dailymotion-element.vue';
import swagDailymotionPreview from '@/components/cms/swag-dailymotion/swag-dailymotion-preview.vue';

export default Vue.extend({
    components: {
        'swag-dailymotion-config': swagDailymotionConfig,
        'swag-dailymotion-element': swagDailymotionElement,
        'swag-dailymotion-preview': swagDailymotionPreview
    },

    data() {
        return {
            location
        };
    },

    created(): void {
        location.startAutoResizer();
    }
});
</script>
```

The individual components are not doing anything special. They are fetching the element with `this.element = await data.get({ id: CONSTANTS.PUBLISHING_KEY });` as stated in the docs and doing some work with it. However, it's always fetching the same element without considering the slot the current element is in, therefore it's always fetching the same data set.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First of all, good question. Right above the `console.error` you pointed to, it checks for the scope of the published data to not have been previously published with another scope via the `_uid` of the corresponding component instance. I feel like this could possibly be an oversight. I'll do some debugging once I can find the time. However, I feel like either the documentation is missing a vital step or this feature is not yet complete.

Comment: After some further digging I can only recommend that you create a ticket on the issue tracker regarding this problem. The pub/sub pattern was design on the assumption that the location id is unique in the published data. Hence why you get redundant data for multiple instances of your component. That means you can't reuse an element with the same id multiple times in the same view, as there's no way to definitely store data for each of them.

Comment: Again, appreciate your help! Feel free to leave an upvote on the ticket I just created: https://issues.shopware.com/issues/NEXT-25102